# Show date only of Modifiend on in email template Crm 2011 online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to ask one question relation to crm 2011 online email template.
In email template, I show Modified On Date. But It shows date and time. I want to show only date. How can achieve this? Please let me know any idea. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported method to do this, however if you really need it, it might be worth trying this (note: I haven't tried this!).

Add your template to a solution (or a test one, for now), export it as unmanaged and edit the `customizations.xml` file. In the XML you will see a representation of your template with the dates in there. Look for the `body` node of your template and you'll see something like this in there (xml, encoded within xml):

```
<body>&lt;?xml version="1.0" ?&gt;
&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"&gt;
&lt;xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/&gt;
&lt;xsl:template match="/data"&gt;
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;font size=2 face="Tahoma, Verdana, Arial"&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Value of Created On: ]]&gt;
&lt;xsl:choose&gt;&lt;xsl:when test="systemuser/createdon"&gt;
&lt;xsl:value-of select="systemuser/createdon" /&gt;
&lt;/xsl:when&gt;&lt;xsl:otherwise&gt;
&lt;/xsl:otherwise&gt;&lt;/xsl:choose&gt;
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Value of Modified On: ]]&gt;
&lt;xsl:choose&gt;&lt;xsl:when test="systemuser/modifiedon"&gt;
&lt;xsl:value-of select="systemuser/modifiedon" /&gt;
&lt;/xsl:when&gt;&lt;xsl:otherwise&gt;
&lt;/xsl:otherwise&gt;&lt;/xsl:choose&gt;
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/font&gt;]]&gt;
&lt;/xsl:template&gt;&lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</body>
```

Try changing any reference like this (note I'm using decoded values here):

```
<xsl:value-of select="systemuser/createdon" />
```

To this

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('systemuser/createdon', 'dd MMM yyyy')"/>
```

Once you're done, save your customisations xml back into your solution zip and upload it. Even if it works when merging, it probably won't work if you try and edit it via the CRM UI.

This comes as an idea from [reading this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx)

Comment: I try as you said but When import, I cannot import and show default error message.

 I try this..

when test="opportunity/modifiedon"&gt;&lt;xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('opportunity/modifiedon', 'dd MM yyyy')"

Btw, I suppect one thing that...
In your example, you show like that
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('systemuser/createdon', 'dd MMM yyyy')"/> 

But when i change, do i need to add "<>" this sign? In customization.xml file, I don't see this sign.
Please let me know my changing is something wrong. Thanks

Comment: No. As I intimated in my response, you will change this `&lt;xsl:value-of select="systemuser/modifiedon" /&gt;` to this `&lt;xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date('systemuser/createdon', 'dd MMM yyyy')" /&gt;`. It may not work anyway - this is the only thing that I can think to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Download the solution
2. Extract the zipped filed
3. search for your field **by the logical name**. So the Modified On field would be `modifiedon`.
4. on every match, add `/@date` after the match. Before: `modifiedon`. After: `modifiedon/@date`
5. Save the file, re-zip the solution folder, import it into the system and publish all customizations.